# Facing issue in elibyy / tcpdf-laravel

Tags: laravel

```
I am using elibyy tcpdf in my laravel project for generting pdf. when I generate pdf it with it, it gives error of ,Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded and on error logs
```

### [2020-06-12 08:57:20] local.ERROR: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded at A:\xampp\htdocs\sprintech\ ate_calculator\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_static.php:1216)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are making your request from the browser. It has max executiong time of 30 seconds. If you want to execute a longer request, you may want to use Beanstalkd or other queue system.

More info you can find on the [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

Comment: THANK YOU @Kristian , it worked for me....actually on local host it was taking more time like around 2,3 mins to generate pdf using fpdf. when I incresed the execution time it worked.

Comment: Glad I could help. I would suggest Mpdf if you are doing more complex things.

Comment: I am just making pdf of a simple html table after rendering my view, its sort of invoice so its working for me now...For future I will consider Mpdf.
thanks once again